# Persisting state in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I was wondering how I should store a particular value and ensure that its changed value is maintained throughout after the button is clicked. For example, after the tick button is clicked, the database will update the value in the task to be true. Subsequently, the button will be disabled.

```
const [taskComplete, setTaskComplete] = setState(false)

<Button onClick={completeTask} disabled={taskComplete}> <FaEye /> <Button>

const completeTask = () => { setTaskComplete(prevBool => !prevBool) }
```

This works and will make the button disabled after it is clicked. However, after I refresh the page, it will be reset and enabled again. How can I ensure that it remains disabled forever?

I was thinking of constantly having API calls to the database to retrieve the value of true in the task but it seems like it may affect performance. Is there any other way? Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to read back the persisted state from the database. With Firebase's realtime listeners that is actually totally reactive, so even if you change the database outside of the app, the app will still respond to that database change and update the UI. Firebase has two databases though, and while both support realtime listeners, the API is different. So have a look at the documentation for realtime listeners of the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

React state is not save permanently. So if you update the browser you will lose that data.

Maybe you could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)